# Bluegiga BLE112: Serial Debugging

Tags: serial, bluetooth, debugging, bluetooth-low-energy

It's my first time to post my question to this electrical engineering.

Anyway, I'm trying to make a BLE gadget using a BLE112-A BlueGiga.

I could update a firmware of BLE112 but I'm stuck with serial debugging by using a FTDI serial to USB adapter. I need your help.

**Goal**

・I want to see debug messages which are incremental counter every second.

**What already works**

・I could update a firmware of BLE112. What I upaded the firmware was this.

https://github.com/slackhappy/ble112/tree/master/serial_debug

**What I am missing**

・I could't see any debug messages on RealTerm.

**What I have devices and firmware**

・A BLE device with a CC-Debuger interface. The data sheet is this.

http://runningele.web.fc2.com/ble/REBLE112FR_sch.pdf

・A FTDI USB to Serial adapter.

http://doc.switch-science.com/datasheets/ssci/FTDI%20USB%20Serial.pdf

・Serial/Console/UART Debugging with the BLE112 made by slackhappy.

https://github.com/slackhappy/ble112/tree/master/serial_debug

・The connection between the BLE device and the FTDI Serial Adapter.

```
BLE device  | FTDI Serial Adapter
P0_2 | DTR
P0_3 | RX
P0_4 | TX
P0_5 | CTS
```

・RealTerm

[image]

As I can see "Status", it seems not be connected correctlly.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks,

---

UPDATE

I confirmed that COM3 is connected to the adapter and the connection is OK.

[image]

Comment: I use RealTerm pretty often and the only thing I'd expect may be lit is CTS with those connections, although I'm not familiar with that module so maybe hardware flow is disabled so that would be off as well. Does typing anything like `AT` or `ATI` give a response?

Comment: @PeterJ

Thanks, I'm so glad to see your comments because I almost gave up receiving any comments. Anyway, how can I type "AT" on RealTerm. Sorry, I'm not familiar with the terminal application. When I try to type in the black background area on the terminal, I cannot get any responses.

Comment: Normally you'd just click in the black area to make sure it has focus and type away, so you might have another problem, but as you type you should see TXD quickly flash.

Comment: @PeterJ Does the TXD mean a light on my FTDI adapter? I can see a light as labeled "TX". If so, the light does not flash. When I plug in USB to the adapter, the light flash for just a moment.

Comment: I was referring to TXD under the status in RealTerm, but it should also flash on the FTDI adapter as well. I'm about to head off soon but something to try would be connecting the TX & RX together on the FTDI adapter and see if characters echo back. I would have thought when you could do a firmware update the hardware should be OK though, maybe also check under device manager that it really is COM3 - maybe the updater does an auto-detect and you're on a different port.

Comment: @PeterJ I attached a screenshot. I confirmed that COM3 is connected to the adapter and the connection is OK. Regarding the TXD, I understood the meaning. For now, my PC and the adapter are connected but the BLE module and the adapter are not connected. In this case, do you think the TXD in RealTerm flash when I type "AT"? I mean that I want to try it more simply.

Comment: If the TX light flash without a connection between the adapter and the BLE module, I may have to check the connection or settings between my PC and the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

In your post, you show (BLE112 on left, FTDI on right of |):

```
BLE device  | FTDI Serial Adapter

P0_2 | DTR
P0_3 | RX
P0_4 | TX
P0_5 | CTS
```

However according to Table 3 in the BLE 112 Data Sheet 1.44 off of the Bluegiga website, the pinouts should be:

```
P0_2 (pin 26) CTS | (FTDI) RTS
P0_3 (pin 25) RTS | (FTDI) CTS
P0_4 (pin 24) TX  | (FTDI) RX
P0_5 (pin 23) RX  | (FTDI) TX
```

These are for USART 1.  There is a different configuration using the same pins for USART 0, but since the one above is what is used in their development board, this leads me to believe it is the default configuration.

BTW what you refer to as a datasheet is actually a schematic of their breakout board.